# MySQL Code First не работает миграция для классов модели с зависимостями

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Изучаю EntityFrameWork. С MSSQL миграция работает отлично, а с MySQL нет.
Код следующий:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual UserDetail Details { get; set; }
}
public class UserDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

В таком виде проходит Add-Migration, создается

```
public partial class Connections : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.UserDetails",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Address = c.String(unicode: false),
                        Phone = c.String(unicode: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Users",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Login = c.String(unicode: false),
                        Password = c.String(unicode: false),
                        Details_Id = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.UserDetails", t => t.Details_Id)
                .Index(t => t.Details_Id);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Users", "Details_Id", "dbo.UserDetails");
            DropIndex("dbo.Users", new[] { "Details_Id" });
            DropTable("dbo.Users");
            DropTable("dbo.UserDetails");
        }
    }
```

А далее при выполнении Update-Database вылетает Exception:

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'AuthAppEntFrame'.
Using NuGet project 'AuthAppEntFrame'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'test' (DataSource: 192.168.23.222, Provider: MySql.Data.MySqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [201809060917211_Connections].
Applying explicit migration: 201809060917211_Connections.
System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.
   в System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   в System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
   в MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateIndexOperation op)
   в MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.<.ctor>b__22_4(MigrationOperation op)
   в MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Update>b__d()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Входная строка имела неверный формат.
```

А вот если в классе User закомментировать `public virtual UserDetail Details { get; set; }` - то Update-Database выполняется и в БД создаются все таблицы. С MSSQL работает без проблем. Подскажите, как выполнить миграцию со связями в MYSQL?!

Comment: у меня такие связи без `virtual` и все работает, EFCore, MySQL

Comment: Попробовал. Такая же песня. Но я использую MySQL.Data.Entiy.EF6 v6.10.8. Попробую еще с файлом конфигурации поиграться. Если не получится попробую через EFCore

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `.Index(t => t.Details_Id)`

Comment: @АртёмОконечников да, получилось. Update-Database прошел, таблицы создались. Но, а как без .Index? Через CreateIndex() тоже не работает.

Comment: Я не сильно компетентен в MySQL, но в случае [`innoDB`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304317/does-mysql-index-foreign-key-columns-automatically) база данных самостоятельно создает индекс на внешнем ключе. Возможно это ваш случай и проблема в этом?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников. Индексы проставлены. Проверил в разных вариантах связей, всё отлично. Спасибо за помощь!